# Как изменить атрибуты тэгов map, area?

Tags: javascript

Как еще можно изменить атрибуты тэгов map, area?
Например, title? Можно ли обратиться к area в цикле, как к дочерним тэгам map?

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
<script>
function Change()
{
  document.getElementById('id1').title='new1';
  document.getElementsByName('name1').item(0).title='new2';
  document.getElementsByName('name2[]').item(0).title='new3';
}
</script>
</head>
<map name="map1">
<area shape="RECT" coords="12,8,92,109" href="#" title="1"  id='id1' />
<area shape="RECT" coords="95,9,175,58" href="#" title="2" name = name1 />
<area shape="RECT" coords="92,62,176,107" href="#" title="3" name = name2[] />
</map>
<img src="map.jpg" usemap="#map1" border="0" />
<input type=button  onClick="Change()" value="Change title">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень даже можно.

Для чтения и записи атрибутов можно использовать setAttribute и getAttribute. Как их использовать - видно в примере ниже. Там же можно подчерпнуть и как получить массив дочерних эелементов, и пример работы с ним.

```
function Change()
{
    var map = document.getElementsByName('map1')[0];
    map.setAttribute('title', 'Новый title');
    alert('Для map установлен title: ' + map.getAttribute('title'));

    //Тут получаем дочерние area
    var maps = map.getElementsByTagName('area');
    for(var i = 0; i < maps.length; i++)
    {
        maps[i].setAttribute('title', 'new' + i);
    }
}
```