# Как узнать событие click без jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Друзья, как определить событие клик без Jquery?

```
$('.show-form').click(function(){

    showModalForm();

    id_form = $(this).data('id-form');
    id_group = $(this).data('id-group');

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если для нескольких элементов, попавших под селектор (как делает ваш пример на jQuery), то примерно так:

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".show-form");

[].forEach.call(divs, function(div) {
  div.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.style.color = "red";
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="show-form">click me 1</div>
<div class="show-form">click me 2</div>
<div class="show-form">click me 3</div>
```

Comment: Уже успел прочитать. А вот сразу следом. как прочитать данные data?

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev data - это обычный аттрибут с префиксом "data-". можно достать через `el.getAttribute('data-id-form');`

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev, задайте лучше отдельный вопрос про `data-*` атрибуты. А еще лучше воспользуйтесь поиском

Comment: Вопрос про `data-` уже точно был.

Comment: @Visman был. но я его не нашел. если найдете - оставьте тут ссылку плз

Comment: @PashaPash, тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/396655/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%82%D1%8D%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2-map-area и получение, и установка атрибутов есть. Да, прада там нет упоминания про `data-`.

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev Атрибуты data-* доступны через dataset. _elem.dataset.idForm_ к примеру.